# Nginx Update writes to /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html files

Tags: nginx

I did a yum update on my Development server and it updated Nginx 1.12.2.3 to Nginx 1.16.1.1.  Also in the process it wrote to the index.html file.

This is of concern as if updates are run on a production server it could cause problems in that it could make the website crash as nginx appear to be writing to the public folder.

Here is how the /usr/share/nginx/html looks before the yum update versus after.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root    root      2811 May 10  2019 poweredby.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root    root       368 May 10  2019 nginx-logo.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root    root      3700 May 10  2019 index.html
-rw-r--r--   1 root    root      3693 May 10  2019 50x.html
-rw-r--r--   1 root    root      3650 May 10  2019 404.html
```

Here is how it looks after the YUM update and reboot.

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root        20 Jan 24 18:28 en-US -> ../../doc/HTML/en-US
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root        18 Jan 24 18:28 img -> ../../doc/HTML/img
drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root        26 Jan 24 18:28 icons
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root        14 Jan 24 18:28 poweredby.png -> nginx-logo.png
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root        25 Jan 24 18:28 index.html -> ../../doc/HTML/index.html
```

So the question is why is YUM/NGINX writing files to the public folder?  As I said this is a concern in that it could bring the whole website down.  Any help, thoughts or suggestions would be welcome.

Regards, 
Patrick

Comment: I'm having trouble following - what changes is it applying to your index.html file?  What you've posted look like directory listing, not html contents.

Comment: Thank you formatting it correctly Richard

Comment: Hello Amoss, What I did was a simple yum update.  The index.html got wrote to.  It seems the file is now replaced by a symbolic link.  The concern here is if I go to the Production server it could crash my site.  So why would Nginx be writing to/ moving the file?  thank you.